# How to resize image to follow canvas size- tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

How can I resize the image into size that I already set on my canvas? Please anyone help me.

```
logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="image1.png")
canvas = Canvas(window ,width= 150 , height= 150)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_image(0,0,image=logo, anchor="center")
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you've done any research, or tried to solve this problem yourself. There are many questions on this site related to resizing images, have you tried searching for them and then applying the answers to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you can't but I suggest resizing the image before and maybe even using a variable for the height and one for the width so as to not make any mistakes.

```
image = image. resize((450, 350), Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

Replace image with logo and the size with your parameters but make sure to keep Image.ANTIALIAS as is.